# Wildfly is trying to gather metrics for a war that doesn't exist anymore

Tags: java, wildfly

The following error keeps showing up in server logs:

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 97) WFLYCTL0017: Operation ("read-resource") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "something.war")]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"deployment\" => \"something.war\")]' not found"
```

`something.war` was undeployed and it was confirmed to not be existing in the deployments folder. Expectation was to not see metrics gathering messages from server for this war.

How can I fix the above issue?

Comment: you sure there is nothing in the standalone.xml ?  What if you go to the admin console

Comment: It's a remote JVM and the admin console is not setup yet. I have also confirmed via management CLI and the above war is not showing up in deployment folder.

Comment: Strange.  maybe stop the service, delete the tmp folder and re-deploy?

Comment: Tried the above steps. Still seeing the same error in logs.

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using? How did you undeploy the application?

Comment: Wildfly 26. We install rpms and have a script which adds/removes wars